# ResponseCache not working in .NET 7 for me

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, .net-7.0

I went through the articles and am testing in localhost. I put a breakpoint on the first line of the action to see if its hits and it hits each time, doesn't seem to cache response.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddResponseCaching();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseResponseCaching();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
        new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3600)
        };

    context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
        new string[] { "User-Agent" };

    await next();
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

//app.UseAuthorization();

//app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

--------------------

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    private RootReportObject? _reportRoot;

    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "User-Agent", Duration = 3600)] //cache for 1 hour for now
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        await DownloadLatestFeedback();
    }
}
```

[image: Program.cs file]

[image: Program.cs file]

[image: Controller]

Comment: How are you testing and what is the response that is send back by the api? Specifically what headers are send back in the response.

Comment: When you send request to this endpoint, Have you set the request header `Cache-Control` to public?

Comment: 1) I don't see `app.MapControllers()` call which is a bit sus 2) How do you test? Try sending requrest via Postman JIC.

Comment: The Cache-Control header is public. Look at the code above

Comment: I don't need MapControllers, in .net 7 for smaller apps they want you to map within program.cs. Look at my MapController call above

Comment: I mean do you add `Cache-Control` to public in header when you send request